# What should my home folder permissions look like?

Tags: macos, permission

I'm trying to figure out the best permissions configuration for my home folder in Sierra.

Would executing this make sense:

```
sudo chown -v -R $(whoami) ~/* && sudo chown -v -R $(whoami) ~/.*; 
sudo find ~/.* -type f -print -exec chmod -v -R 640 {} \;
sudo find ~/.* -type f -print -exec chmod -v -R 750 {} \;
```

I'm looking for everything to work, but I want to restrict access as much as possible. My permissions were set to read-only to "Everyone" (no idea why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My home folder's permissions look like this (`drwxr-xr-x+`):

[image: Home folder permissions]

However, folders inside my home folder (like Desktop) look like this (`drwx------+`):

[image: Desktop permissions]

Ultimately, the best permissions for your home folder are likely the defaults. As long as everything *inside* your folder is restricted, you'll be okay. [Apple also doesn't recommend changing the permissions for your home folder.](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203538) If you really want to, though, you can try it out and just use the following Terminal command to reset the permissions:

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```