# After downgrade account to standard user not able to login

Tags: macbook-pro, password, user-account, login, ventura

After downgrade an account to standard, this user is not able to log in. After reboot came up a login window, then progress bar and then a login window again. There message is "After reboot Touch-ID on your mac needs a password". The password field is only shaking and I couldn't get the desktop, but I'm able to ssh and also login the standard user from terminal and remote. If I change the account back to administrator, the user is able to log in normally. I also have tested to remove the Apple account with no success.

How can I debug this event? How can I solve the problem to downgrade this user to standard without losing the profile/account?

Path to solution:

- [Debug what is preventing login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/322768/289098) / *not helpful*
- [Reset password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/178843/289098)  / *not successful*
- [Check and switch off and on again FileVault](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277590/289098)   / *not successful*
- [Reset user permission of Users Home folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/272571/289098) / *not successful*

Answer (score -1):

When I do this I make a new account for each user.

I make sure that the Admin account stays original.

That way I don't risk messing up the Admin account.

Comment: Yes, this is also my standard procedure. But I have to downgrade this account for some reasons.

Comment: Can you maybe try my procedure careful, to see if this is the same behavior on your machine?

Comment: @lemrm I described the procedure for you that I use on my machine. So as for behavior it works.

Comment: I understand your point. My admin account is okay and not messed up. This was a second admin user on my machine and for safety reason I like to downgrade now.